# How to pass values in JSON for the Ecto Query?

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

The client sends the following JSON: {"user": {"age+":18,"age-":40}}

In my controller I have the following:

```
def procura(conn, query) do
  maior = conn.params["user"]["age+"]
  menor = conn.params["user"]["age-"]
 query = from u in query, where: u.age > ^maior and u.age < ^menor, select: u.name
  pesquisa = Repo.all query
  IO.puts pesquisa
end
```

But I got the compiler warning: `** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for %{}`

How do I pass the values in JSON for the Ecto query?

My goal is to do a query based on JSON fields. I want to query for users who have between x and y years.
*Automatically translated.*

Comment: What's the value of query? You seem to be passing `%{}` as the second argument to `procura` instead of a query. Also, you need to change the `from` line to `query = from u in query, ...`.

Comment: Is procura an action? If yes then query will parameters scrubbed from request. Pls try IO.inspect on query at show as the result. It should be a map. If it is an action you should return a connection.

Comment: Hello! My goal is to do a search based on JSON fields. I want to search for users who have between x and y years. I'm not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might wanted to do is:

In my controller I have the following:

```
def procura(conn, %{"user" => %{ "idade+" => maior, "idade-" => menor }}) do
  query = from u in Module.Model, where: u.idade > ^maior and u.idade < ^menor, select: u.name
  pesquisa = Repo.all query
  IO.puts pesquisa
  text conn, "Works"
end
```